# testing database application remotely

Tags: sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008

With advice from users here I was able to deploy an application that connects with sql server 2008 database on to a server. I have the connection string with data source pointing to my machine since the database is stored on my machine temporarily.
I do not have access to another machine and wanted to test the application so I remotely connected to the server to test the application and it does not connect to the server. I have TCP/IP enables, port to default 1433, and remote connections checked.
Is there something I am missing? Please help

Comment: Are you connecting through a firewall?

Comment: yes,  but I checked my firewall settings to ensure sql server instance and browser were added as exceptions

Comment: I had this problem before, and (this sucks I know) I can't remember the exact location, but sql server uses a range of ports for the actual instances.  You can configure it to use just one port instead and I had to end up doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Can you connect to the remote server using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?  You will need to modify your connection string to point to the remote server as well.

Comment: how do I connect through Sql server management studio? the remote server I am using now does not have sql server installed on it. could that be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Using [plink](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html), sometimes I connect to a remote sql server by running this command to open an ssh tunnel

```
plink.exe -v -c -l username -pw mypassword -L 2433:localhost:1433 myserver.com
```

Then I can connect to the server through SQL Server Management Studio using 127.0.0.1,2433 as the server name and username/password as the credentials. Note, SQL Server authentication must be enabled for this to work. Here's a [link](http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/HowToSetUpARemoteSQLServerConnection) that describes the process in more detail

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I have a .net application front end that is being deployed and in my configuration settings I have the connection string added. Why would I have to use plink to be able to connect? Do I need to make changes in my program as well?